# Как сделать скриншот элемента с элементами svg на сайте?

Tags: javascript, svg, png

создал конструктор на сайте суть которого в том, что он на выбранный посетителем фон и цвет фона ( фон в png ) добавляет выбранные им же элементы и их цвета( элементы в svg ), а затем надо нажать на кнопку "сохранить результат"  и выполняется скриншот только рабочей области. Написал таков скрипт, НО он делает скриншот, но только фон, а  выбранные и установленные svg игнорирует ( на скриншот их нет - просто фон), есть идеи почему так, но не знаю как исправить и возможно ли исправить.
Заранее спасибо)

JavaScript необходимый для создания скриншота вынес в .html файл и кину сюда.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
<title>Fence</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-block">
    <div id="input-block">
       <label>Задайте высоту панели <input type="number"  placeholder="100"> см</label>
    </div>
    <div id="fence-container">
               <div class="half-container" index="10">
                <div class="hint" style="top: 45px; bottom: 45px; height: auto;" >
                    Выбор цвета
                </div>
               <div class="strap-block"  index="0" style="left: 0px; top: -43px">
                   <div class="strap-item">
                   </div>
                   <div class="hint" >
                       Выбор планки и цвета
                   </div>
               </div>
                <div class="strap-block"  index="1" style="left: 0px; top: 0px">
                    <div class="strap-item">
                    </div>
                    <div class="hint" >
                        Выбор планки и цвета
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="strap-block"  index="2" style="left: 0px; bottom: 0px">
                    <div class="strap-item">
                    </div>
                    <div class="hint" >
                        Выбор планки и цвета
                    </div>

                </div>

        </div>
            <div class="half-container" index="11">
                <div class="strap-block"  index="3" style="left: 0px; top: 0">
                    <div class="strap-item">
                    </div>
                    <div class="hint" >
                        Выбор планки и цвета
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="strap-block"  index="4" style="left: 0; bottom: 0px">
                    <div class="strap-item">
                    </div>
                    <div class="hint" >
                        Выбор планки и цвета
                    </div>
                </div>




                <div class="hint" style="top: 45px; bottom: 45px; height: auto;" >
                    Выбор цвета
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" onclick="a()">Сохраните свой результат!</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
 <script>
    function a(){
        html2canvas(document.querySelector(".fence-container")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
    }

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Без Вашего кода едва ли что то получится угадать

Comment: Замечание понял, сейчас добавлю

Comment: а html2canvas у Вас откуда и какой он версии?

Comment: Скачивал файлом с одной статьи, которую писали 07.02.2019

Comment: попробуйте с гитхаба взять последнюю версию, на англоязычном stackoverflow пишут что проблема с этим решена

Comment: Вас понял, попробую, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь это поможет, однако у этого способа есть 2 особенности:

1. Обязателен `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`, иначе канва будет пустая
2. Стили должны быть внутри `svg`, иначе они не подействуют

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function () {
  var data = document.querySelector('div#svg').innerHTML;
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(data);
  img.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('canvas#copy')
            .getContext('2d')
            .drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```css
div, body, svg {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="svg">
  <svg width="150" height="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g fill="none" stroke-width="2.2" transform="translate(75,75)">
    <circle r="10" stroke="hsl(10,75%,75%)"/>
    <circle r="15" stroke="hsl(10,75%,75%)"/>
    <circle r="20" stroke="hsl(40,75%,75%)"/>
    <circle r="25" stroke="hsl(70,75%,75%)"/>
    <circle r="30" stroke="hsl(100,75%,75%)"/>
    <circle r="35" stroke="hsl(130,75%,75%)"/>
    <circle r="40" stroke="hsl(160,75%,75%)"/>
    <circle r="45" stroke="hsl(190,75%,75%)"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<div>
  <button>>></button>
</div>

<canvas width="150" height="150" id="copy"></canvas>
```

Comment: Вас понял, спасибо, попробую и отпишу))

Comment: но он не нарисует html, совместить с выводом html2canvas наверное надо будет вручную..

Comment: У меня svg добавляются непосредственно через js, на странице отсутствует тег svg как как таковой, попробую тогда немного переделать ваш код

Comment: @АртёмЧерницкий покажите пример

Comment: @АртёмЧерницкий давайте попробуем тут =) https://syncfiddle.net/fiddle/-Lbqzt89kLC3f15lXmLR

Comment: https://www.useloom.com/share/616b38d1c9b34879910b8b013ae6b5d1 для удобства видео заделал)

Comment: @АртёмЧерницкий а на странице они как выглядят, если результирующую разметку смотреть?

Comment: https://www.useloom.com/share/5adb15fdf0574209b354ff56c0643274 Как-то так)

Comment: @АртёмЧерницкий а картинка через css задается?

Comment: Если вы про фон, то добавляю так же через JS

Comment: Проблема в том, что в начале не было необходимости делать этот скриншот, иначе делалось бы иначе, но имею то что имею..Сам дурак как говорится

Comment: @АртёмЧерницкий я все равно не понимаю где картика, как она попадет на экран, какой элемент рисует браузер чтобы полявилась картинка

Comment: https://www.useloom.com/share/328a54e4af5547898945fdaf0ac3bc9f вот))